# When do errors in .d.ts files affect consumers?

Tags: typescript, declaration-files

If a TS file consumes a .d.ts file that contains errors, sometimes the consumer cannot build because of these errors. Other times, TS silently converts the problematic types to `any`.

What are the rules for when TS chooses to report these errors? I haven't found any pattern.

Comment: Do you have `skipLibCheck` in all cases?  I'm guessing syntax errors would probably be reported as TS can't really make sense of a malformed file, semantic errors are easier to ignore ..

Comment: skipLibCheck isn't enabled. Even in those cases, there are sometimes errors and sometimes not.